# How to use barchart widget in odoo? What type of functional field i have to use?

Tags: widget, odoo

I want to display a bar chart on my form view, What type of functional field i have to use? What that functional field returns? Thanks in advance..

Comment: did you try anything so far ?

Comment: No. Not tried anything related to bar chart

Answer (score 0):

Just we need to do the barchart widget from the following way:

**Field Calculation Function :**

```
def _get_daily_statistics(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context=None):
    """ Get the daily statistics of the mass mailing. This is done by a grouping
    on opened and replied fields. Using custom format in context, we obtain
    results for the next 6 days following the mass mailing date. """
    obj = self.pool['mail.mail.statistics']
    res = {}
    for mailing in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        res[mailing.id] = {}
        date = mailing.sent_date if mailing.sent_date else mailing.create_date
        date_begin = datetime.strptime(date, tools.DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT)
        date_end = date_begin + relativedelta.relativedelta(days=self._period_number - 1)
        date_begin_str = date_begin.strftime(tools.DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT)
        date_end_str = date_end.strftime(tools.DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT)
        domain = [('mass_mailing_id', '=', mailing.id), ('opened', '>=', date_begin_str), ('opened', '<=', date_end_str)]
        res[mailing.id]['opened_daily'] = json.dumps(self.__get_bar_values(cr, uid, obj, domain, ['opened'], 'opened_count', 'opened:day', date_begin, context=context))
        domain = [('mass_mailing_id', '=', mailing.id), ('replied', '>=', date_begin_str), ('replied', '<=', date_end_str)]
        res[mailing.id]['replied_daily'] = json.dumps(self.__get_bar_values(cr, uid, obj, domain, ['replied'], 'replied_count', 'replied:day', date_begin, context=context))
    return res
```

**Field which is add as the function field from my side.**

```
    'opened_daily': fields.function(
        _get_daily_statistics, string='Opened',
        type='char', multi='_get_daily_statistics',
    ),
```

**Field which is as the function field in  XML View side**

```
<field name="opened_daily" string="Opened Daily" widget="barchart"/>
```

The different different widgets are available in Odoo I am just show off you the **barchar widget**

I hope this should helpful for you ..:)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I read this method on mass_mail.py. But i didn't understand the function __get_bar_values(). and How to assign axis for this chart. ie, x and y axis of the chart. Please explain this. Thanks in advance

Comment: okey let me check from my side and then after I will tell  you